# Magento2 : What is the difference between regular price and final price?

Tags: magento2

What is the difference between regular price and final price in magento2?

```
product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount();
```

and

```
$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
```

Comment: Regular price is product's original price where as final price is discounted price or special price..

Comment: thanks @Bhagyashree . I am use this in excluding and including tax way. so is it perfect for it?

Comment: No, its not perfect for that.

Comment: so can you please know me what is the best way to get excluding and including tax value of products?

Comment: [Refer to this link](https://gielberkers.com/get-product-price-including-excluding-tax-magento-2/)

Answer (score 3):

1. Price in the sense of cost of the product.
2. Where as Regular price is product's original price.
3. And Final price is discounted price or special price.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I can't accept it because of in comment already I got the answer and also there is also discussion of excluding and including tax way. your answer is well but you can understand that. thank you very much again.